# OData filter on computed value

Tags: entity-framework, odata, calculated-columns

I have a `Person` with a name, split into `FirstName` and `LastName`. I need to filter by `FullName` which is First- and Last-Name combined.

How will I be able to filter that?

> ~/odata/people?$filter=...

Keep in mind I need to be able to filter a person named `FirstName=Foo, LastName=Bar` by the following:

- foo bar
- foo
- bar
- oo ba

If this isn't possible directly in the query. Then I've been looking at [DelegateDecompiler](http://daveaglick.com/posts/computed-properties-and-entity-framework), though I haven't been able to make it work just yet. So also looking for advice on that approach is a good choice.

Comment: http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part1-protocol.html can build in function help? like contains(FirstName,'foo') & cantains(..)

Comment: Using contains won't work because it needs to check a single string that is not split into first- and lastname. So it will fail on contains(FirstName, 'foo bar') & contains(LastName, 'foo bar')

Comment: contains(concat(concat(FirstName,'  '), LastName), 'foo bar') ?

Comment: That actually works! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part1-protocol.html check build in functions, contains(concat(concat(FirstName,' '), LastName), 'foo bar')

:)

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of this. It's so straight forward :)

Comment: I hope next time you may help our community to answer these questions :)